# Google Sheets: Money Jar Bar Chart

Tags: google-sheets, bar-chart, google-barchart

I am working on a personal project on Google Sheets for a video game I'm playing. I want to make a sort-of Money Jar with a single column bar graph. Here is the data I'm referencing:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zihwc.png).

Preferably, I want a bar chart with a single column. The cash goals would be my data points on the Y-Axis of the chart (75,000, 120,000, etc.). For example, as I reached the 75,000 cash goal in my video game, I enter the date I reached this goal into the "Date" column. As a number is entered into this cell, the bar chart fills to the 75,000 data point on my chart. Here is a very rough sketch of what I hope it would look like: [Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnxlO.png).

I'm not sure how I would do this but any suggestions or comments would be very helpful. (Also, I've made a separate chart for the cash values alone (separate from values and text in the above chart) which looks like this: [Value Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SynsK.png).)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Add a column to the data by `=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,MAX(IF(B2:B<>"",A2:A))))`

| Value | Date | Latest Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 75,000 | 08.11.21 | 120,000 |
| 120,000 | 08.14.21 | 120,000 |
| 200,000 |  |  |

2. Create an `Area Chart`

- X-axis: `B2:B`
- Series 1: `A2:A`
- Series 2: `C2:C`

3. In `Setting` tab, check `use Column B as label`
4. In `Customize` tab, under `Series`, check `Data Label`
5. Also, change the `Line Opacity` of `Series 1` to `0%`